# Eloquent : delete rows from multiple table with same id

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am a bit new to Laravel. I am trying to delete a `project` from a table along with its `images` and `plans` from 2 other tables. How to do this in Laravel Eloquent?

Here is the `delete` controller of the project:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $project = Projects::findOrFail($id);
        $project->delete();
        return Redirect::to('admin/view-project')->with('message', 'Project deleted successfully');
    }
```

How can I get this to be done from the model? I didn't understand that.

Here is the `Projects` model:

```
class Projects extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'project_info_arabic';

    public function projectImages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ProjectsImage');
    }

    public function projectPlans()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ProjectsPlans');
    }
}
```

Can kindly anybody help?

Comment: Have you created any relation between your projects plans and images table??. I mean have you used Laravel relations?

Comment: @Bashar Nozibulla do you mean `hasMany` yes I think it's clear in the question!!

Comment: If you understand laravel relations then during creating the tables use ondelete cascade. I mean in your plans and images table there will be a foreign key i think as you have defined the relations. Right now I am telling that when you created the foreign key use ondelete cascade `$table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');` use this way in your plans and images table

Comment: @Bashar Nozibulla yes I working on this solution just now, thanks will come back to you if I face any problems will repost on that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way when thinking about data consistency is the implementation of foreign keys on the database layer. That does it automatically for you and you don't need to think about it anymore.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: will try this and come back to you

Comment: this was helpful for Laravel beginner like me thanks

Comment: More than welcome. This doesn't necessarily have something to do with Laravel, thats purely Database related. Interesting to know that Laravel supports creating the keys out of the box. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You could try model events in laravel.Check this

```
class Projects extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        Projects::deleted(function($project)
        {
            $project->projectImages()->delete();
            $project->projectPlans()->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I try this but got `Class 'ProjectsImage' not found `